# Discord.js - How to send YouTube url after searching for a video

Tags: discord.js, youtube-api

So basically, my idea for a new command for my discord bot is a "link searcher", which will be a searching command that sends the url of the video that is chosen by the user. Something like in the image attached.

[image: example]

What I already have made is a searching command with embed, but im not quite sure how to send the video url that gets chosen via reaction. Any ideas/solutions?

Comment: How do you get the video titles? A video URL may be included in the metadata you're given

Comment: Please attach your code alongwith your query so it can help us provide a better solution

Comment: @Elitezen Ok, you indeed made me think of a solution, thank you! I'll answer my own question with the code in case anyone needs it too.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution after some tries, so here's the final code.

```
//////CONFIG LOAD///////////
////////////////////////////
const ytsr = require("youtube-sr")
const { Client, Collection, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { attentionembed } = require("../util/attentionembed"); //attentionembed is an embed i pre-made for errors/attention cases for when the user gets one
const { approveemoji, denyemoji, PREFIX, } = require(`../config.json`); //my config contains the definitions for "yes" and "no" emojis, together with the bot token
////////////////////////////
//////COMMAND BEGIN/////////
////////////////////////////
module.exports = {
  name: "linkfor",
  aliases: ["searchlink","findlink","link","lf"], //optional
  cooldown: 3, //optional

  async execute(message, args, client) {
    //if its not in a guild return
    if (!message.guild) return;
    //react with approve emoji
    message.react(approveemoji).catch(console.error);
    //if the argslength is null return error
    if (!args.length)
      return attentionembed(message, `Usage: ${message.client.prefix}${module.exports.name} <Video Name>`)
    //if there is already a search return error
    if (message.channel.activeCollector)
      return attentionembed(message, "There is a search active!");
    //define search
    const search = args.join(" ");
    //define a temporary Loading Embed
    let temEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor("Searching...", "put a gif link here if you want")
      .setColor("#F0EAD6")
    //define the Result Embed
    let resultsEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Results for ")
      .setDescription(`\`${search}\``)
      .setColor("#F0EAD6")
      .setAuthor("Search results:", "put a gif link here if you want")
      .setFooter("Respond with the right number", "put a gif link here if you want")
    //try to find top 9 results
    try {
      //find them
      const results = await ytsr.search(search, { limit: 9 });
      //map them and sort them and add a Field to the ResultEmbed
      results.map((video, index) => resultsEmbed.addField(video.url, `${index + 1}. ${video.title}`));
      //send the temporary embed aka Loading... embed
      const resultsMessage = await message.channel.send(temEmbed)
      //react with 9 Numbers
      await resultsMessage.react("1️⃣");
      await resultsMessage.react("2️⃣");
      await resultsMessage.react("3️⃣");
      await resultsMessage.react("4️⃣");
      await resultsMessage.react("5️⃣");
      await resultsMessage.react("6️⃣");
      await resultsMessage.react("7️⃣");
      await resultsMessage.react("8️⃣");
      await resultsMessage.react("9️⃣");
      
      //edit the resultmessage to the resultembed (you can also try deleting and sending the new one, if you need to)
      await resultsMessage.edit(resultsEmbed)
      //set the collector to true
      message.channel.activeCollector = true;
      //wait for a response
      let response;
      await resultsMessage.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == message.author.id,
        { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'], }).then(collected => {
          //if its one of the emoji set them to 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 / ...
          if (collected.first().emoji.name == "1️⃣") { return response = 1; }
          if (collected.first().emoji.name == "2️⃣") { return response = 2; }
          if (collected.first().emoji.name == "3️⃣") { return response = 3; }
          if (collected.first().emoji.name == "4️⃣") { return response = 4; }
          if (collected.first().emoji.name == "5️⃣") { return response = 5; }
          if (collected.first().emoji.name == "6️⃣") { return response = 6; }
          if (collected.first().emoji.name == "7️⃣") { return response = 7; }
          if (collected.first().emoji.name == "8️⃣") { return response = 8; }
          if (collected.first().emoji.name == "9️⃣") { return response = 9; }
          //otherwise set it to error
          else {
            response = "error";
          }
        });
      //if response is error return error
      if (response === "error") {
        //send error message
        attentionembed(message, "Please use the right emoji symbol.");
        //try to delete the message
        return resultsMessage.delete().catch(console.error);
      }
      //get the response link
      const URL = resultsEmbed.fields[parseInt(response) - 1].name;
      //set collector to false aka off
      message.channel.activeCollector = false;
      //send the collected url
      message.channel.send(URL);
      //delete the search embed (optional, for better displaying)
      resultsMessage.delete().catch(console.error);
      //catch any errors while searching
    } catch (error) {
      //log them
      console.error(error);
      //set collector false, just incase its still true
      message.channel.activeCollector = false;
    }
  }
};
```